# How to get font name set for TessBaseAPI read

Tags: c++, tesseract, leptonica

Using standard tess api to recognize text:

```
image1 = imread("/home/user/Desktop/src.png");
cv::cvtColor(image1, image1, COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
cv::threshold(image1, image1, 125, 255, THRESH_BINARY);
tesseract::TessBaseAPI *api = new tesseract::TessBaseAPI();
if (api->Init(NULL, "eng")) {
fprintf(stderr, "Could not initialize tesseract.\n");
exit(1);
};
api4->SetImage((uchar*)image1.data, image1.size().width, image1.size().height, image1.channels(), image1.step1());
char *outText = api->GetUTF8Text();
cout << "outText:" << outText << endl;
```

Need to train tesseract to recognize more precisely some symbols

Using the guide below:

jTessBox Editor:  https://sourceforge.net/projects/vietocr/files/jTessBoxEditor/

> Step 1: Make box files for images that we want to train
> Syntax: tesseract [langname].[fontname].[expN].[file-extension] [langname].[fontname].[expN] batch.nochop makebox
> Eg:tesseract train.my.exp0.tif train.my.exp0 batch.nochop makebox
>
> {*Note: After making box files we have to change or modify wrongly identified characters in box files.}
>
> Step 2: Create .tr file (Compounding image file and box file)
> Syntax: tesseract [langname].[fontname].[expN].[file-extension] [langname].[fontname].[expN] box.train
> Eg: tesseract train.my.exp.tif train.my.exp0 box.train
>
> step 3: Extract the charset from the box files (Output for this command is unicharset file)
> Syntax: unicharset_extractor [langname].[fontname].[expN].box
> Eg: unicharset_extractor train.my.exp0.box
>
> step 4: Create a font_properties file based on our needs.
> Syntax: echo "[fontname] [italic (0 or 1)] [bold (0 or 1)] [monospace (0 or 1)] [serif (0 or 1)] [fraktur (0 or 1)]" [angle bracket should be here] font_properties
> Eg: echo "arial 0 0 1 0 0" [angled bracket] font_properties
>
> Step 5: Training the data.
> Syntax: mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O [langname].unicharset [langname].[fontname].[expN].tr
> Eg: mftraining -F font_properties -U unicharset -O train.unicharset train.my.exp0.tr
>
> Step 6:
> Syntax: cntraining [langname].[fontname].[expN].tr
> Eg: cntraining train.my.exp0.tr
> {*Note:After step 5 and step 6 four files were created.(shapetable,inttemp,pffmtable,normproto) }
>
> Step 7: Rename four files (shapetable,inttemp,pffmtable,normproto) into ([langname].shapetable,[langname].inttemp,[langname].pffmtable,[langname].normproto)
> Syntax: rename filename1 filename2
> Eg:
> rename shapetable train.shapetable
> rename inttemp train.inttemp
> rename pffmtable train.pffmtable
> rename normproto train.normproto
>
> Step 8: Create .traineddata file
> Syntax: combine_tessdata [langname].
> Eg: combine_tessdata train.
>
> Move .traineddata file to tesseract programs tessdata directory
> C:\Program Files\Tesseract-OCR\tessdata
>
> Run tesseract for trained fronts
>
> tesseract Test2.png stdout -l train

I'm confused with font name, as I don't know the font name.

> step 4: Create a font_properties file based on our needs.
> Syntax: echo "[fontname] [italic (0 or 1)] [bold (0 or 1)] [monospace (0 or 1)] [serif (0 or 1)] [fraktur (0 or 1)]" [angle bracket should be here] font_properties
> Eg: echo "arial 0 0 1 0 0" [angled bracket] font_properties

How to get font name set for  TessBaseAPI read with c+  and command line?

Answer (score 0):

```
tesseract::ResultIterator* res_it = api4->GetIterator();

const char* word = res_it->GetUTF8Text(tesseract::RIL_WORD);
const char *font_name;

bool bold, italic, underlined, monospace, serif, smallcaps;
int pointsize, font_id;
 font_name = res_it->WordFontAttributes(&bold, &italic, &underlined, &monospace, &serif,&smallcaps, &pointsize, &font_id);
                                                                
printf("%s \t=> fontname: %s, size: %d, font_id: %d, bold: %d,"\
       " italic: %d, underlined: %d, monospace: %d, serif: %d,"\
       " smallcap: %d\n", word, font_name, pointsize, font_id,
       bold, italic, underlined, monospace, serif, smallcaps);
```

does the trick, but tesseract representive mentioned somewhere that it might not be that reliable

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).